# Newrelic: ignore specific part of transaction

Tags: php, monitoring, newrelic

For some service we want to see only few parts of every transaction - all except external web services.

I've found `newrelic_ignore_apdex` and `newrelic_ignore_transaction` methods [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/php-agent/configuration/php-agent-api).
But calling of this methods will ignore whole transaction not only specific part.

Is there way to completely ignore a part of transaction?

[image: newrelic example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your needs, it might be more appropriate to use

newrelic_end_of_transaction ( ) or newrelic_end_transaction ( [ignore] ) 
to stop th transaction from being recorded at a certain point

together with newrelic_start_transaction (appname [, license] )
if you need to reopen the transaction later on.

you find both of them here https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/php-agent/configuration/php-agent-api

Quoting from NewRelic docs

> newrelic_end_of_transaction ( )
>
> ```
> function newrelic_end_of_transaction (): null
> ```
>
> Stop recording the web transaction immediately. Usually used when a
>   page is done with all computation and is about to stream data (file
>   download, audio or video streaming, etc.) and you don't want the time
>   taken to stream to be counted as part of the transaction. **This is
>   especially relevant when the time taken to complete the operation is
>   completely outside the bounds of your application**. For example, a user
>   on a very slow connection may take a very long time to download even
>   small files, and you wouldn't want that download time to skew the real
>   transaction time.

on the other hand here is the description of the start function

> newrelic_start_transaction (appname [, license] )
>
> ```
> function newrelic_start_transaction (string $appname, string $license = ini_get('newrelic.license')): bool
> ```
>
> If you have ended a transaction before your script terminates (perhaps
>   due to it just having finished a task in a job queue manager) and you
>   want to start a new transaction, use this call. This will perform the
>   same operations that occur when the script was first started. Of the
>   two arguments, only the application name is mandatory. However, if you
>   are processing tasks for multiple accounts, you may also provide a
>   license for the associated account. The license set for this API call
>   will supersede all per-directory and global default licenses
>   configured in INI files. This function will return true if the
>   transaction was successfully started.

Please note some difference between newrelic_end_transaction ( [ignore] ) and newrelic_end_of_transaction ( )

> Despite being similar in name to newrelic_end_of_transaction above,
>   this call serves a very different purpose. newrelic_end_of_transaction
>   simply marks the end time of the transaction but takes no other
>   action. The transaction is still only sent to the daemon when the PHP
>   engine determines that the script is done executing and is shutting
>   down. This function on the other hand, causes the current transaction
>   to end immediately, and will ship all of the metrics gathered thus far
>   to the daemon unless the ignore parameter is set to true. In effect
>   this call simulates what would happen when PHP terminates the current
>   transaction.

Know I did a lot of quoting, but the documentation is so explicit that I found useless to say the same things in a different way.
Hope this will help